# How to get the character from unicode code point in PHP?

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding

For example,

how to get the character corresponding to **U+010F**?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');

function mb_html_entity_decode($string)
{
    if (extension_loaded('mbstring') === true)
    {
        mb_language('Neutral');
        mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
        mb_detect_order(array('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-15', 'ISO-8859-1', 'ASCII'));

        return mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
    }

    return html_entity_decode($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
}

function mb_ord($string)
{
    if (extension_loaded('mbstring') === true)
    {
        mb_language('Neutral');
        mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
        mb_detect_order(array('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-15', 'ISO-8859-1', 'ASCII'));

        $result = unpack('N', mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UCS-4BE', 'UTF-8'));

        if (is_array($result) === true)
        {
            return $result[1];
        }
    }

    return ord($string);
}

function mb_chr($string)
{
    return mb_html_entity_decode('&#' . intval($string) . ';');
}

var_dump(hexdec('010F'));

var_dump(mb_ord('ó')); // 243
var_dump(mb_chr(243)); // ó
```

Comment: Anyone who is using this code and upgrading to PHP 7.2 mbstring needs to remember to wrap these functions in an `if (!function_exists('mb_ord')` and ` `if (!function_exists('mb_chr')` or remove them completely as they are now added in 7.2 mbstring

Comment: mb_chr: I rewrote it using `pack()`, it's probably marginally faster: `function mb_chr($id) { return mb_convert_encoding(pack("N", $id), "UTF-8", "UCS-4BE"); }`

Answer (score 5):

I just wrote a `polyfill` for missing multibyte versions of `ord` and `chr` with the following in mind:

- It defines functions `mb_ord` and `mb_chr` only if they don't already exist. If they do exist in your framework or some future version of PHP, the polyfill will be ignored.
- It uses the widely used `mbstring` extension to do the conversion. If the `mbstring` extension is not loaded, it will use the `iconv` extension instead.

---

**EDIT :**

I added functions for HTMLentities encoding / decoding and encoding / decoding to JSON format as well as some demo code for how to use these functions

---

### **Code** :

```
if (!function_exists('codepoint_encode')) {
    function codepoint_encode($str) {
        return substr(json_encode($str), 1, -1);
    }
}

if (!function_exists('codepoint_decode')) {
    function codepoint_decode($str) {
        return json_decode(sprintf('"%s"', $str));
    }
}

if (!function_exists('mb_internal_encoding')) {
    function mb_internal_encoding($encoding = NULL) {
        return ($from_encoding === NULL) ? iconv_get_encoding() : iconv_set_encoding($encoding);
    }
}

if (!function_exists('mb_convert_encoding')) {
    function mb_convert_encoding($str, $to_encoding, $from_encoding = NULL) {
        return iconv(($from_encoding === NULL) ? mb_internal_encoding() : $from_encoding, $to_encoding, $str);
    }
}

if (!function_exists('mb_chr')) {
    function mb_chr($ord, $encoding = 'UTF-8') {
        if ($encoding === 'UCS-4BE') {
            return pack("N", $ord);
        } else {
            return mb_convert_encoding(mb_chr($ord, 'UCS-4BE'), $encoding, 'UCS-4BE');
        }
    }
}

if (!function_exists('mb_ord')) {
    function mb_ord($char, $encoding = 'UTF-8') {
        if ($encoding === 'UCS-4BE') {
            list(, $ord) = (strlen($char) === 4) ? @unpack('N', $char) : @unpack('n', $char);
            return $ord;
        } else {
            return mb_ord(mb_convert_encoding($char, 'UCS-4BE', $encoding), 'UCS-4BE');
        }
    }
}

if (!function_exists('mb_htmlentities')) {
    function mb_htmlentities($string, $hex = true, $encoding = 'UTF-8') {
        return preg_replace_callback('/[\x{80}-\x{10FFFF}]/u', function ($match) use ($hex) {
            return sprintf($hex ? '&#x%X;' : '&#%d;', mb_ord($match[0]));
        }, $string);
    }
}

if (!function_exists('mb_html_entity_decode')) {
    function mb_html_entity_decode($string, $flags = null, $encoding = 'UTF-8') {
        return html_entity_decode($string, ($flags === NULL) ? ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 : $flags, $encoding);
    }
}
```

### **How to use** :

```
echo "Get string from numeric DEC value\n";
var_dump(mb_chr(50319, 'UCS-4BE'));
var_dump(mb_chr(271));

echo "\nGet string from numeric HEX value\n";
var_dump(mb_chr(0xC48F, 'UCS-4BE'));
var_dump(mb_chr(0x010F));

echo "\nGet numeric value of character as DEC string\n";
var_dump(mb_ord('ď', 'UCS-4BE'));
var_dump(mb_ord('ď'));

echo "\nGet numeric value of character as HEX string\n";
var_dump(dechex(mb_ord('ď', 'UCS-4BE')));
var_dump(dechex(mb_ord('ď')));

echo "\nEncode / decode to DEC based HTML entities\n";
var_dump(mb_htmlentities('tchüß', false));
var_dump(mb_html_entity_decode('tch&#252;&#223;'));

echo "\nEncode / decode to HEX based HTML entities\n";
var_dump(mb_htmlentities('tchüß'));
var_dump(mb_html_entity_decode('tch&#xFC;&#xDF;'));

echo "\nUse JSON encoding / decoding\n";
var_dump(codepoint_encode("tchüß"));
var_dump(codepoint_decode('tch\u00fc\u00df'));
```

### **Output** :

```
Get string from numeric DEC value
string(4) "ď"
string(2) "ď"

Get string from numeric HEX value
string(4) "ď"
string(2) "ď"

Get numeric value of character as DEC int
int(50319)
int(271)

Get numeric value of character as HEX string
string(4) "c48f"
string(3) "10f"

Encode / decode to DEC based HTML entities
string(15) "tch&#252;&#223;"
string(7) "tchüß"

Encode / decode to HEX based HTML entities
string(15) "tch&#xFC;&#xDF;"
string(7) "tchüß"

Use JSON encoding / decoding
string(15) "tch\u00fc\u00df"
string(7) "tchüß"
```

Comment: This (very nice) answer can be improved if you mention explicitly whether the functions accept/generate the Unicode code point value—for instance, `0x010F` for the `U+010F` character mentioned in the question (rather than e.g. `0xC48F` in UTF-8). `UCS-4BE` suggests it does.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: I updated the code to allow UCS-4BE / UTF-32 based Unicode code point values, to provide encoding / decoding for HTML entities and to provide encoding / decoding for JSON. I also added some example code to illustrate how to use these functions.

Answer (score 3):

In case this is useful to anyone, PHP 7.2 has now added the `mb_ord` and `mb_chr` equivalents to `ord` and `chr`. For example the following code will work in PHP 7.2

```
$charPoint = "U+010F";
echo mb_chr(hexdec(substr($charPoint,2)); // prints ď
```

This has 2 side effects (a) One does not need to implement their own and (b) if one has already implemented their own they need to wrap it in a `if (!function_exists('mb_chr'))`

Answer (score 2):

[IntlChar](http://php.net/IntlChar) is a new ICU-based builtin class released with PHP/7 that exactly addresses this problem:

> IntlChar provides access to a number of utility methods that can be used to access information about Unicode characters.

```
// PHP 7.0 and later
var_dump(
  "\u{010F}" === IntlChar::chr(0x010F),
  0x010F === IntlChar::ord("\u{010F}")
);

// PHP 7.2.0-dev
var_dump(
  "\u{010F}" === mb_chr(0x010F, "UTF-8"),
  0x010F === mb_ord("\u{010F}", "UTF-8")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you control the UTF-8 encode of your strings (as recommended by latin and other european standards), you need only

```
html_entity_decode($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

See Example #1 of [php man](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php). You can change the second parameter to ENT_NOQUOTES, etc. and, **pay attetion**, use ENT_XHTML, etc. if your string is a Markup Language (!).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function chr_utf8($n,$f='C*'){
return $n<(1<<7)?chr($n):($n<1<<11?pack($f,192|$n>>6,1<<7|191&$n):
($n<(1<<16)?pack($f,224|$n>>12,1<<7|63&$n>>6,1<<7|63&$n):
($n<(1<<20|1<<16)?pack($f,240|$n>>18,1<<7|63&$n>>12,1<<7|63&$n>>6,1<<7|63&$n):'')));
}

echo chr_utf8(hexdec('010F'));

// Output the UTF-8 character corresponding to U+010F
```