# converting unicode to normal characters before displaying on webpage

Tags: php, html, unicode

I'm using openinviter class to import the contacts from email. However, it displays the Unicodes of non-english characters (for example, polish), such as u0117 (and similar type of other codes) instead of normal characters. Is there anyway that I can convert the unicodes to characters and then display them?

Here is the original code of the page:
http://pastebin.com/d0tkpxbv

Thanks.

Comment: What language? What platform? Can you post your code?

Comment: I just added the link in my original post, please check. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use preg_replace() to convert the value to its hexadecimal numeric entity:

```
<?php
$text = 'Wladisu0142aw';
$text = preg_replace('/u([0-9a-f]{4})/i', '&#x$1;', $text);
echo $text;  //displays Wladisław
?>
```

Comment: This does not address the _backslash_ that is usually just before the _u_. Those will be left behind in the result. The _$text_ variable should be: _Wladis\u0142aw_

Answer (score 0):

try this one:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php

Answer (score 0):

The following code allows you to decode the characters as well as re-encode them if necessary

### **Code** :

```
if (!function_exists('codepoint_encode')) {

    function codepoint_encode($str) {
        return substr(json_encode($str), 1, -1);
    }

}

if (!function_exists('codepoint_decode')) {

    function codepoint_decode($str) {
        return json_decode(sprintf('"%s"', $str));
    }

}
```

### **How to use** :

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 

var_dump(codepoint_encode('ඔන්ලි'));
var_dump(codepoint_encode('සින්ග්ලිෂ්'));

var_dump(codepoint_decode('\u0d94\u0db1\u0dca\u0dbd\u0dd2'));
var_dump(codepoint_decode('\u0dc3\u0dd2\u0db1\u0dca\u0d9c\u0dca\u0dbd\u0dd2\u0dc2\u0dca'));
```

### **Output** :

```
string(30) "\u0d94\u0db1\u0dca\u0dbd\u0dd2"
string(60) "\u0dc3\u0dd2\u0db1\u0dca\u0d9c\u0dca\u0dbd\u0dd2\u0dc2\u0dca"
string(15) "ඔන්ලි"
string(30) "සින්ග්ලිෂ්"
```

If you want more complex functionality, see [How to get the character from unicode code point in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365583/how-to-get-the-character-from-unicode-value-in-php/24755772#24755772).

Comment: In your decode function you need to escape double quotes that could be in _$str_. Otherwise bad things will happen.