# PHP - convert unicode to character

Tags: php, unicode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the character from unicode value in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365583/how-to-get-the-character-from-unicode-value-in-php)
>   [PHP: Convert unicode codepoint to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805802/php-convert-unicode-codepoint-to-utf-8)

How can I convert a unicode character such as `%u05E1` to a normal character via PHP?

The `chr` function not covering it and I am looking for something similar.

Comment: Please define what a "normal character" is to you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"%uXXXX" is a non-standard scheme for URL-encoding Unicode characters. Apparently it was proposed but never really used. As such, there's hardly any standard function that can decode it into an actual UTF-8 sequence.

It's not too difficult to do it yourself though:

```
$string = '%u05E1%u05E2';
$string = preg_replace('/%u([0-9A-F]+)/', '&#x$1;', $string);
echo html_entity_decode($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

This converts the `%uXXXX` notation to HTML entity notation `&#xXXXX;`, which can be decoded to actual UTF-8 by `html_entity_decode`. The above outputs the characters "סע" in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Nothing short of genius!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`hexdec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php) to convert it to it's decimal representation first.

```
echo chr(hexdec("05E1"));
var_dump(hexdec("%u05E1") == hexdec("05E1")); //true
```

Comment: `chr` only handles code points defined in ASCI, it won't handle multi-byte Unicode characters. The above `echo`s "?".