# can I get the unicode value of a character or vise versa with php?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

Is it possible to input a character and get the unicode value back? for example, i can put &#12103 in html to output "⽇", is it possible to give that character as an argument to a function and get the number as an output without building a unicode table?

```
$val = someFunction("⽇");//returns 12103
```

or the reverse?

```
$val2 = someOtherFunction(12103);//returns "⽇"
```

I would like to be able to output the actual characters to the page not the codes, and I would also like to be able to get the code from the character if possible.
The closest I got to what I want is php.net/manual/en/function.mb-decode-numericentity.php but I cant get it working, is this the code I need or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: Related: [How to get the character from unicode code point in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1365583/2943403) and [ord() doesn't work with utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35575721/2943403) and [How do I display extended ascii characters in my php code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74045685/2943403) and [UTF-8 safe equivalent of javascript's charCodeAt() in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10333098/2943403) and [Searching for a good Unicode-compatible alternative to the PHP ord() function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11304582/2943403)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
function _uniord($c) {
    if (ord($c[0]) >=0 && ord($c[0]) <= 127)
        return ord($c[0]);
    if (ord($c[0]) >= 192 && ord($c[0]) <= 223)
        return (ord($c[0])-192)*64 + (ord($c[1])-128);
    if (ord($c[0]) >= 224 && ord($c[0]) <= 239)
        return (ord($c[0])-224)*4096 + (ord($c[1])-128)*64 + (ord($c[2])-128);
    if (ord($c[0]) >= 240 && ord($c[0]) <= 247)
        return (ord($c[0])-240)*262144 + (ord($c[1])-128)*4096 + (ord($c[2])-128)*64 + (ord($c[3])-128);
    if (ord($c[0]) >= 248 && ord($c[0]) <= 251)
        return (ord($c[0])-248)*16777216 + (ord($c[1])-128)*262144 + (ord($c[2])-128)*4096 + (ord($c[3])-128)*64 + (ord($c[4])-128);
    if (ord($c[0]) >= 252 && ord($c[0]) <= 253)
        return (ord($c[0])-252)*1073741824 + (ord($c[1])-128)*16777216 + (ord($c[2])-128)*262144 + (ord($c[3])-128)*4096 + (ord($c[4])-128)*64 + (ord($c[5])-128);
    if (ord($c[0]) >= 254 && ord($c[0]) <= 255)    //  error
        return FALSE;
    return 0;
}   //  function _uniord()
```

and

```
function _unichr($o) {
    if (function_exists('mb_convert_encoding')) {
        return mb_convert_encoding('&#'.intval($o).';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
    } else {
        return chr(intval($o));
    }
}   // function _unichr()
```

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for the code. Is this from somewhere online with an explanation on how it works?

Comment: It's code I use in PHPExcel; but I can't recall where I got it from now, or find a reference to its source... but it's used in a number of libraries

Comment: The first function takes a string (a Unicode character consists of several octets), checks the first bits of the first octet to find out the length of the character in octets (I think it's using UTF8).
Then strips the control bits from every octet, and turns the remaining bits (those forming the unicode character itself) into the number you want.  That conversion is straightforward, just turning the integer to string.

Comment: You are a lifesaver!! Thank you!

Answer (score 26):

Here's a more compact implementation of unichr/uniord based on `pack`:

```
// code point to UTF-8 string
function unichr($i) {
    return iconv('UCS-4LE', 'UTF-8', pack('V', $i));
}

// UTF-8 string to code point
function uniord($s) {
    return unpack('V', iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-4LE', $s))[1];
}
```

Comment: I think it should have been UTF-32LE, not UCS*. But the trick is definitely creative.

Answer (score 25):

If you're using PHP7.2 (or later), you don't need to define a new function. There are two functions for your purposes from [Multibyte String extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php)!

To get code point of a character (i.e. Unicode value), use [mb_ord()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ord.php); and to get a specific character from that value, use [mb_chr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-chr.php).

E.g.:

```
mb_chr(12103, "UTF-8"); // ⽇
mb_ord("⽇", "UTF-8"); // 12103
```

Answer (score 10):

This also works, (for someone who understands bitshifting this might be more readable than  Mark Bakers answer):

```
public function ordinal($str){
    $charString = mb_substr($str, 0, 1, 'utf-8');
    $size = strlen($charString);        
    $ordinal = ord($charString[0]) & (0xFF >> $size);
    //Merge other characters into the value
    for($i = 1; $i < $size; $i++){
        $ordinal = $ordinal << 6 | (ord($charString[$i]) & 127);
    }
    return $ordinal;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tested your answer vs Marks and I think there is an issue with yours (because I am not good with bit shifting I dont know what).

    echo "<p>".ordinal("響")." :: "._uniord("響")."</p>";

Returns:

    105 :: 38911

(it should be 38911)

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. The error seems to be in the default encoding mb_internal_encoding(), if that is not 'utf-8' retrieving the first character fails. I have fixed this by explicitly adding the encoding to mb_substr.

Comment: I up voted as it works now, but will leave the answer as it was. Thanks for the alternative

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following **deprecated** functions

For encoding

```
string utf8_encode ( string $data )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

For decoding

```
string utf8_decode ( string $data )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php

Also check

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

```
<?php


echo htmlspecialchars_decode("&#12103");//will print ⽇

?>
```

Comment: hello Akhil, I have looked at these but they only work with the ascii range characters, anything above that becomes gibberish.

Comment: hello @Akhil, thanks, this works, shame there is no encode option.

Comment: UTF-8 is a Unicode encoding, not Unicode. utf8_decode does not give me the unicode value of the character I pass it (what the question asked for). The question asked about `12103` specifically, where `utf8_encode` and `utf8_decode` both return the same number(/string) that it was passed instead of a unicode character.