# Match special kind of whitespace

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like that (it's an empty paragraph) saved from my heavily edited and after-processed input from TinyMCE.

That is how it looks like after echo, in HTML source code in browser:

```
<p> </p>
```

Now, I need to remove those empty paragraphs.

I have already tried

```
$output = str_ireplace("<p> </p>", "", $string);
$output = preg_replace("/<p> <\/p>/", "", $string);
$output = preg_replace("/<p>[ \t\n\r]*<\/p>/", "", $string);
$output = preg_replace("/<p>[\s]*<\/p>/", "", $string);
```

and many more variations with no luck. It's still there, intact. I have also tried mb_ereg_replace and matching `&nbsp;` which isn't apparently the case.

On the other hand, this works:

```
$output = preg_replace("/<p>.*<\/p>/", "", $string);
```

but of course striping also paragraphs with actual content.

What else could that "space-like" character be? How am I supposed to match it?

**SOLVED**
Thanks to Ibizaman and this thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361303/can-i-get-the-unicode-value-of-a-character-or-vise-versa-with-php), I've found the character. It is nbsp in unicode value. See http://unicodelookup.com/#160/1

This works:

```
$output = preg_replace("/<p>[\x{00A0}\s]*<\/p>/u", "", $string);
```

As pointed by mcrumley, this might work even better:

```
"/<p>[\p{Zs}\s]*<\/p>/iu"
```

Comment: Are you sure its not your browser simply adding the space in the HTML source for display purposes? What if you save the page and view it in a text editor such as [notepadd++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)?

Comment: "/<p>[^a-zA-Z0-9]*<\/p>/" should do it, although it's maybe too restrictive. The rationale is that a ^ at the beginning of the brackets negates it.

Comment: What about `<p>[^<]*<\/p>`... Anyway, check the page source to be sure... I remember last time, a similar situation made me crazy :S

Comment: Using `#<p>\s*</p>#` should work. What's the exact output ? Could you give the hex value of those spaces ? A wild guess, try to use the `u` modifier `#<p>\s*</p>#u`

Comment: @Mike: it looks like a normal space after saving and opening in PsPad for example; I have also those <p></p> in the string and those are easily removed

Comment: @Enissay: it does remove also paragraphs with content

Comment: @HamZa: either one isn't working

Comment: @ibizaman: "/<p>[^a-zA-Z0-9]*<\/p>/" is a good idea, it works as a nice workaround, but I might have to enhance it a bit, thanks. At least something.

Comment: @Saix yes indeed, that's why I said it's too restrictive. Try parsing you string with functions outputting unicode values (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361303/can-i-get-the-unicode-value-of-a-character-or-vise-versa-with-php) SO question). Then you'll see what's really going on.

Comment: @ibizaman: I've found the bastard... [link](http://unicodelookup.com/#160/1)

Comment: Your character class is not doing exactly what you think it is doing. `[\x{00a0}|\s]` matches non-breaking space, white space, and the pipe character "|". You can take out the "|".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't know which character is being outputted, first parse the output of `$string` with functions outputting unicode values (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361303/can-i-get-the-unicode-value-of-a-character-or-vise-versa-with-php) SO question).

Or, you can proceed the other way around and only accept well-formed paragraphs:

```
$output = preg_replace("/(<p>[^a-zA-Z0-9]*<\/p>)/", "\1", $string);
```

*Disclaimer : I already put this in comments but since it solved the problem, it's better placed in an answer for future reference, I think*.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Unicode character property to match all spaces. `\p{Zs}` is "Space separator" and includes space, non-breaking space, thin space, etc. You can also use `\pZ` to match all separators, including line separator and paragraph separator. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php for details.

```
$output = preg_replace("/<p>[\p{Zs}\s]*<\/p>/iu", "", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

A 'space-like character' is `\s`, which would make your entire line

```
$output = preg_replace("/<p>\s*<\/p>/", "", $string);
```

See [an example](http://regex101.com/r/xX6zA8) on regex101.com.

Comment: He already tried that `<p>[\s]*<\/p>`, and no you don't need to escape the backslash in this case.

Comment: Just to be sure, I have tried this one too. Doesn't work either.

Comment: Well, it _does_ work. I'll update my answer with a link to regex101.com

Comment: @SQB well of course it would work for "normal spaces" but the OP surely doesn't have normal spaces `0x20` or there is another problem in the code (logic).