# PHP wont recognise double line feed

Tags: php, regex, restructuredtext

I am running a RST to php conversion and am using preg_match.

this is the rst i am trying to identify:

```
An example of the **Horizon Mapping** dialog box is shown below. A 
summary of the main features is given below. 

.. figure:: horizon_mapping_dialog_horizons_tab.png 

   **Horizon Mapping** dialog box, *Horizons* tab 

Some of the input values to the **Horizon Mapping** job can be changed 
during a Workflow using the internal programming language, IPL. For 
details, refer to the *IPL User Guide*.
```

and I am using this regex:

```
$match = preg_match("/.. figure:: (.*?)(\n{2}[ ]{3}.*\n)/s", $text, &$result);
```

however it is returning as false.
here is a link of the expression working on regex
http://regex101.com/r/oB3fW7.

Comment: Have you tried `\r\n`?

Comment: yes i have, i used \r?\n\r?\n

Comment: Why the `s` flag? You do have a newline at the end of your input? How do you check the result? It seems like `\R` should work, can you add more info?

Comment: I used the s flag because I read on a similar problem that the s flag did something with a double line feed
he $match variable is a boolean value and will return true if a match is found
yes there is a new line after the text
I have updated the question with more rst

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the line break is `\n`, is doubt, use `\R`:

```
$match = preg_match("/.. figure:: (.*?)(\R{2}[ ]{3}.*\R)/s", $text, &$result);
```

`\R` stands for either `\n`, `\r` and `\r\n`

Comment: it still wont find it, if i remove a line and only search for one line feed it works however the second messes it up

Answer (score 0):

My instinct would be to do some troubleshooting around the `s` flag as well as the `$result` variable passed by reference. To achieve the same without any interference from dots and the return variable, can you please try this regex:

```
..[ ]figure::[ ]([^\r\n]*)(?:\n|\r\n){2}[ ]{3}[^\r\n]*\R
```

In code, please try exactly like this:

```
$regex = "~..[ ]figure::[ ]([^\r\n]*)(?:\n|\r\n){2}[ ]{3}[^\r\n]*\R~";
if(preg_match($regex,$text,$m)) echo "Success! </br>";
```

**Finally:**

If this does not working, you might have a weird Unicode line break that php is not catching. To debug, for each character of your string, iterate through all the string's characters

1. Iterate: `foreach(str_split($text) as $c) {`
2. Print the character:  `echo $c . " value = "`
3. Print the value from [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9361531/1078583): `.  _uniord($c) . "<br />"; }`

Comment: The regex you provided didnt work, however I tried the uniord and it gave me a weird output that the line feeds were spaces, and the 3 spaces before the ** on the second line were not even there, is there a site where I could upload my files you you to see what I mean?
$result is also returning an emtpy array