# How to convert unicode in php?

Tags: php, unicode

I want to convert my string to Unicode like if "ग" than give output like "0917" or "917" any one of them.

[Link for Unicode of string i want](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0900-097F)

Please give me a Hint i used `ord()` but it's not work proper.

```
$ord = mb_convert_encoding("ग", 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
echo $ord;

$ord = ord("ग");
echo $ord;    // 224 output
```

Both try but not working.

Comment: Instead of the link (that could break), please include any relevant code and data in your question please.

Comment: ‘Not working’ is a *really* poor description of a problem. What happened? Did it print the wrong value? Did it not print anything? Did something catch fire? (Note that those values are in hexadecimal, so if you got 2327 instead of 917 you're seeing the decimal value.)

Comment: [Here][1] you can find a working answer:


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361303/can-i-get-the-unicode-value-of-a-character-or-vise-versa-with-php

Comment: @LWjuniOr Thanks for help it's useful for me can you please comment it i can accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iconv — Convert string to requested character encoding

http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php