# How can I turn "Escape characters" into "normal characters"?

Tags: php, unicode, html-escape-characters

for example this is an escape chars:

```
.\33 u, .\33 u\24, .\33 u\28 1\29, .\33 u\24\28 1\29 { width: 25%; clear: none; }
```

Is there an algorithm or an online tools to turn it into Normal characters?

Comment: Normal character like?

Comment: For example I know "\33 u" in unicode is "3u"

Comment: this? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361303/can-i-get-the-unicode-value-of-a-character-or-vise-versa-with-php