# bin2hex return different result with psot function

Tags: php, unicode

I am working on my own project that require the conversion from Chinese char to Unicode.

Currently, i am using the code below with no problem

```
base_convert(bin2hex(iconv("utf-8", "ucs-4", '人')), 16, 16) // Return 4eba
```

However, as I trying to add a form to convert the char that user input, the result were way different

```
base_convert(bin2hex(iconv("utf-8", "ucs-4", $_POST["char"])), 16, 16) // Return 2600000023000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Beware that `base_convert()` is possibly alright for individual characters but it's totally unsuitable for general strings because it works with actual numbers and you'll get in trouble as soon as you get an integer larger than `PHP_INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get UTF-8 in the `$_POST` array you need to tell the browser that the form is to be submitted in UTF-8.

Generally the way to achieve this is to serve the page containing the form with an indicator that the page is encoded as UTF-8. Otherwise, the browser will arbitrarily guess which encoding is in use, and that guess probably won't be UTF-8. To indicate UTF-8 set the `Content-Type` header or include in the `<head>`:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

If you include the character `人` in a form field and the browser thinks the encoding is one (like cp1252 Western European) that does not include the character `人`, it will panic and send instead an HTML-character-reference-encoded version, `&#20154;`. This is a non-useful data mangling as you can't tell whether the original input was `人` or `&#20154;`, but it's an historical browser quirk we will now never get rid of.

This is why you get `2600000023000000`: characters U+0026,U+0023 are the leading `&#` part of that mangled version. The rest of that string is `00` and not the subsequent characters because `base_convert` deals with floating-point numbers and `0x2600000023000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` is far too ludicrously large a number to retain precision.

If you are trying to convert UTF-8-encoded characters into numeric code points, try [`uniord`/`unichr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27444149/18936).