# Exploding Song title

Tags: php

I am having some issues exploding this title **Song Artist – Song Name** I am using the following code and having not very much luck.

```
$title2 = $html2->find('header.section-header h2',0);
$links = $title2->plaintext;
$str = explode ("–", $links);
$artist = preg_replace('#\[[a-zA-Z].*\]#','',$str[0]);
$song = preg_replace('#\[[a-zA-Z].*\]#','',$str[1]);
print '<div class="song"> <div class="options"> <a class="play" href="'.$url.'"  data-url="'.$url.'" data-title="'.$artist.'"> </a> <a class="download" href="'.$url.'"> </a> </div> <div class="info"> <a class="direct" href="'.$url.'"> <div class="artist">'.$artist.'</div> <div class="title">A Rainy Night In Harlem (Freestyle)</div> </a> </div> </div>';
```

It should look like this when I display.
[image]

But instead it returns something that looks like this.
[image]

Comment: Whats ur error or problem? be clear and specifc

Comment: This is a poor approach I fear: If both the artist or the songtitle contains a - your approach fails. In case they don't contain a -, describe please what you expect, and what you get. I don't understand what you are doing with the regex or what it is you try to achieve.

Comment: @ErwinMoller once again, view update..

Comment: simply output the variables you filled: $artist and $song. DO they contain what you expect? Maybe you only fill artist?

Comment: @ErwinMoller it does not explode the song name at all..

Comment: @ErwinMoller view here http://dl.wubstub.com/stream/index.php?a=Angel+Gold+Ft.+Ty+Dolla+Sign%2C+BigTC+%26amp%3Bamp%3B+TeeCee4800+&s=+No+No+No&mp3=http://www.dopefile.me/mp3embed-xni34a6ptemt.mp3

Comment: Just debug. echo $links, echo $str[0], echo $str[1], etc. Maybe the - isn't the - you use? (unicode?)

Comment: @ErwinMoller I've been messing with all of those things, but no luck.. I don't know why it's not exploding it.. makes no sense to me.

Comment: If you KNOW for sure $links contain a - it should explode. I bet the "-" you use in your explode doesn't match the one in $links. Have look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361303/can-i-get-the-unicode-value-of-a-character-or-vise-versa-with-php try the accepted anser, function _uniord($c) to see if the characters have the same code.

Comment: @ErwinMoller I created a fiddle with all of my code please check it.. http://viper-7.com/hBZfzX I am getting so confused :| if it's not in the foreach you can explode it just fine.. so I am SURE it's using that - bracket

Comment: I'll check the code locally. fiddle gives me errors: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GearmanException' with message 'Failed to set exception opti.... etc. I'll be back soon

Comment: @ErwinMoller thanks!

Comment: I'll post an "answer" because it doesn't fit here.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the dash character is actually a `-`? There are a number of dashes and hyphens in the UTF-8 character set; if it's one of those, then your explode won't see them. You'll need to either ensure that your input text contains only one specific kind of dash, or else use a `preg_split()` to split on any of them. Also be aware that some song titles and artist names may also contain dashes, so be careful about using it as an arbitrary split character.

Comment: Please consider upvoting helpful answers to be thankful of time and effort people invest on your problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something that might interest you:

Add `echo htmlentities($title)."<br>";` under `$title2=$title->plaintext;`, IN YOUR ORIGINAL code. Like this

```
$title2 = $title->plaintext;
echo htmlentities($title)."<br>";
```

Gives me: (for example:)

```
<h2 itemprop="name"><a href="http://www.DailyNewSounds.com/singles">Chris Brown &#8211; You Make Me This Way (I Got You) (LQ)</a></h2>

No - but a &#8211;
```

That is why the explode didn't work. You might get away with exploding on `&#8211;`

Checked it over here, and it seems to work.

Sorry for all the edits, I had a hard time displaying `&#8211;` :-)

Comment: This fixed it thank you so much Erwin, extremely blessed that you decided to take the time out of your day to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

You may use `trim` to remove any unwanted whitespaces:

```
<?php
$title2 = $html2->find('header.section-header h2',0);
$links = $title2->plaintext;
$str = explode ("–", $links);
$artist = trim($str[0]);
$song = trim($str[1]);
?>
<div class="song">
    <div class="options">
        <a class="play" href=""  data-url="" data-title=""></a>
        <a class="download" href=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        <a class="direct" href="">
            <div class="artist"><?php echo $artist;?></div>
            <div class="title"><?php echo $song;?></div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```