# How do I display extended ascii characters in my php code?

Tags: php, utf-8, character, ascii, decode

I'm trying to decode a text that contains extended ASCII characters but when I try to convert the character I get the wrong value. Like this:

```
    echo "“<br>";
    echo ord("“")."<br>";
    echo chr(ord("“"))."<br>";
```

And this is my output:

```
“
226
�
```

The ASCII value of the character "“" is 147, not 226. And instead of the � symbol, I want to get "“" character back.

I'm using UTF-8

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

I have tried changing to different charsets but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st** `U+201C` [Left Double Quotation Mark](https://unicode-table.com/en/201C/) is UTF-8 byte sequence `E2 80 9C` (hexadecimal) i.e. decimal `226 128 156`

**2nd** `ord` — [Convert the first byte of a string to a value between 0 and 255](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php)

**Result**: `ord("“")` returns `226`…

Instead of `ord` and `chr` pair, use `mb_ord` and its complement `mb_chr`, e.g. as follows:

```
<?php
echo "“<br>";
echo mb_ord("“")."<br>";
echo mb_chr(mb_ord("“"))."<br>";
?>
```

Result: `.\SO\74045685.php`

> “
> 8220
> “

**Edit** you can get *Windows-1251* code (`147`) for character `“` (U+201C,  *Left Double Quotation Mark*) as follows:

```
echo ord(mb_convert_encoding("“","Windows-1251","UTF-8"));  //147
```

Answer (score 0):

You're incorrect about the `“` character, the UTF-8 encoding is two bytes: `c293`.

See: [SET TRANSMIT STATE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0093/index.htm).

In the manual for [ord()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) it says:

> However, note that this function is not aware of any string encoding,
> and in particular will never identify a Unicode code point in a
> multi-byte encoding such as UTF-8 or UTF-16.

On top of this, if I actually convert the `'“'` charachter to hexadecimal, I get: `e2809c`. So it's a triplet. Never trust what you read online.

See: https://3v4l.org/57UV8

Answer (score 0):

There is no ASCII representation for “, as has already been said it is multibyte, UTF-8 to be precise:

```
echo mb_detect_encoding("“"); // UTF-8
```

ord() and chr() don't support this, you're only looking at the first byte of up to four needed for a particular character. Fortunately there are functions that does:

```
echo "“\n"; // “
echo mb_ord("“")."\n"; // 8220
echo mb_chr(mb_ord("“")); // “
```

But why do you need to transform it back and forth? It seems you already have the character in your code :), not as a value but as the actual visual representation.

Comment: I have a task to decode a string by adding a certain number to the bytes of the characters, but it looks like its more complicated than just using char(ord($char) + x) :(

Comment: Do you have an example? Like “ should yield the character *, or something? You _could_ probably add a number to the codepoint, I'm just not sure that's what you want. It might be though.