# Convert unreadable characters in to Unicode characters

Tags: php, javascript

When I call some facebook info from the opengraph I get some names that look like this.

**\u0d94\u0db1\u0dca\u0dbd\u0dd2 \u0dc3\u0dd2\u0db1\u0dca\u0d9c\u0dca\u0dbd\u0dd2\u0dc2\u0dca**

Is there a way to convert them in to readable unicode characters using PHP or Javascript? **PHP is more preferred.** Thanks

Comment: Did you search to see whether this question had already been answered? See, e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365583/how-to-get-the-character-from-unicode-value-in-php)

Comment: @cjh it's in javascript, I'd rather prefer a way using PHP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `json_decode()`:

```
$str = '\u0d94\u0db1\u0dca\u0dbd\u0dd2';
echo json_decode('"'.$str.'"'); // ඔන්ලි
```

[Codepad Example](http://codepad.org/08rJtfJb)

Answer (score 0):

The following code allows you to decode the characters as well as re-encode them if necessary

### **Code** :

```
if (!function_exists('codepoint_encode')) {

    function codepoint_encode($str) {
        return substr(json_encode($str), 1, -1);
    }

}

if (!function_exists('codepoint_decode')) {

    function codepoint_decode($str) {
        return json_decode(sprintf('"%s"', $str));
    }

}
```

### **How to use** :

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 

var_dump(codepoint_encode('ඔන්ලි'));
var_dump(codepoint_encode('සින්ග්ලිෂ්'));

var_dump(codepoint_decode('\u0d94\u0db1\u0dca\u0dbd\u0dd2'));
var_dump(codepoint_decode('\u0dc3\u0dd2\u0db1\u0dca\u0d9c\u0dca\u0dbd\u0dd2\u0dc2\u0dca'));
```

### **Output** :

```
string(30) "\u0d94\u0db1\u0dca\u0dbd\u0dd2"
string(60) "\u0dc3\u0dd2\u0db1\u0dca\u0d9c\u0dca\u0dbd\u0dd2\u0dc2\u0dca"
string(15) "ඔන්ලි"
string(30) "සින්ග්ලිෂ්"
```