# PHP function chr and ord with special chars

Tags: php, character, encode, chr, ord

In PHP when I use the `ord` function in order to catch the ASCII code of my character I get this behavior:

```
ord("a") // return 97
chr(97) // return a
```

But when I use a special character like `Œ` the returns are different:

```
ord("Œ") // return 197
chr(197) // return �
```

All of my pages are encoded in utf8. This behaviour is the same for most of the special characters.

Has somebody seen this problem in the past? How can I fix it?

Comment: `ord` only works on single-byte characters. If used on a multibyte character only the first byte will be returned, which is why you are getting weird results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the character from unicode value in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365583/how-to-get-the-character-from-unicode-value-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

`ord()` and `chr()` both use the ASCII values of characters, which is a single byte encoding.  Œ is not a valid character in ASCII.

You can get each byte of a multi-byte character by specifying the byte offset, as follows:

```
$oethel = "Œ";
$firstByte = ord($oethel[0]); // 197
$secondByte = ord($oethel[1]); // 146
```

Reversing the process, however, does not work, because assigning to a string byte offset converts that string to an array:

```
$newOethel = "";
$newOethel[0] = chr(197);
$newOethel[1] = chr(146);
echo $newOethel;
// Output is as follows: 
// PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion
// Array
```

Comment: "assigning to a string byte offset converts that string to an array" — only for zero-length strings. If you had `$newOethel = "?";` then the output would be `Œ` ([demo](https://3v4l.org/9QrAu)).

Answer (score 0):

The black diamond with a question mark is a display problem.

Review the details of black diamond in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1766831  .  There are two cases; see which one fits.