# Convert both, Unicode entities and HTML entities

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

After spending the entire morning going through questions on Stack Overflow, I'm seeking help. I need to convert both, Unicode entities and HTML entities into UTF-8 text.

```
$string = "Let&#039;s &quot;Kiss &amp; Makeup&quot;";
//-> Let's Kiss & Makeup "lalala"
```

I manage to decode the HTML entities alone (using `html_entity_decode()` and `htmlspecialchars_decode`). Not even this widely linked [Polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24755772/1329116) does the trick. Since none of the functions I tried decoded Unicode entities, I haven't even tried figuring out how a combination of decoding functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue is specifically with single quotes and the default [`ENT_COMPAT` flag of `html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode), which "leaves single-quotes alone". Simply set the `ENT_QUOTES` flag instead to convert all quotes:

```
echo html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8');
```