# Random string by encoding

Tags: php, string, random, encoding

I need logic or some package with functionality to generate random string with specific encoding without using base function random_bytes etc.

Something like this:

```
$randomLine = random_string($length = 10, $encoding = 'UTF-16');
```

Comment: What exactly is this going to be used for?

Comment: Do you need the string need to be randomly spread over all the characters in the given encoding? Or could you generate a random string in a more simple encoding (say ASCII) and then convert it? Because the former will be considerably harder. Also *without using base function random_bytes etc* - why? Because again, that's going to be much more difficult. What *can* you use?

Comment: @iainn 
I need this specific functionality for hard tests of my service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have php 7.2+, you can use `mb_chr`, like this

```
<?
$max = 10;
$out = '';
$encoding = 'UTF-16';
for ($i = 0;$i<$max;$i++) {
    if ($s = mb_chr(rand(1,1114112), $encoding)) {
        $out .= $s;
    }
}

echo $out;
```

See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a4d39412005473231317758ca5d2fc8d4ad0b27b

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point There are 1114112 unicode code points.

Comment: Is there any variants for php with version less than 7.2?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365583/how-to-get-the-character-from-unicode-code-point-in-php, specifically the second answer (polyfill for mb_chr)