# PHP - How to decode or parse emoji from unicode string?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, unicode-string, unicode-escapes

In my PHP code, I receive user's emoji as this string "1f49c" from frontend app.

It should be as simple as `echo "\u{1f49c}";`, but my data is only this string: "1f49c"

How to parse it to ?

I've tried:

```
$emoji = "1f49c";
$reaction = "\u".$emoji;
json_decode("\"$reaction\"");
```

but it results: `Ὁc` not

Comment: As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47592489/12763954): `mb_chr(hexdec($emoji))`