# concatenating uppercase letters of two separate strings in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, scanf

I am doing practice questions for an upcoming exam but cant seem to figure out a question where the objective is:

Write a C program to read two strings `s1` and `s2`. The maximum size of each string is 25. Form two new strings called `upper` and `lower`. Lower consists of the lowercase letters of `s1` and `s2` concatenated while `upper` contains the concatenation of the uppercase letters of both strings.

eg: 
Input:

> s1: GREENblue
>  s2: busCAR

Output:

> upper: GREENCAR
>  lower: bluebus

I've been attempting this for a few days but have not been able to completely figure it out.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    char s1[25];
    char s2[25];
    char upper[25];
    char lower[25];

    printf ("Please enter first string: ");
    scanf ("%s", &s1);
    printf ("Please enter second string: ");
    scanf ("%s", &s2);

    strcat (s1, s2);

    for (i=0; i<strlen(s1); i++)
    {
        if (s1[i]>=65 && s1[i] <= 90)
        {
            upper[i] = s1[i];
        }
        else
        {
            lower[i] = s1[i];
        }
    }
    printf ("Upper: %s\n", upper);
    printf ("Lower: %s\n", lower);
}
```

Comment: `scanf ("%s", &s1);` --> `scanf ("%24s", s1);`, same for `s2`

Comment: any particular reason for the downvote? On both the question and the first answer?!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you got the general idea but missed a few details which are important:

- don't use `strcat` to concatenate the two strings. You already have each one of them in their own buffer plus, if you are going to do this you have better make sure you have enough memory for the larger resulting string.
- `if (s1[i]>=65 && s1[i] <= 90)` this condition is good to check for upper case letters but it's negation leaves you with everything else, which includes lower case letters, numbers, etc. So it better to have 3 cases (uppercase, lowercase, everything else) just to be safe).
- if you are going to print the content of the upper/lower arrays, make sure you append the `'\0'` character so they are interpreted as strings by your print function.

  ```
  j=0; //iterator for lower
  k=0; //iterator for upper
  for (i=0; i<strlen(s1); i++)
  {
      if (s1[i]>='A' && s1[i] <= 'Z') // a bit more clear
      {
          upper[k++] = s1[i];
      }
      else
      {
          if (s1[i]>='a' && s1[i] <= 'z')
          {
               lower[j++] = s1[i];
          }
          else
          {
              //print something or just exit...
          }
       }
  }

  for (i=0; i<strlen(s2); i++)
  {
      if (s2[i]>='A' && s2[i] <= 'Z') // a bit more clear
      {
          upper[k++] = s2[i];
      }
      else
      {
          if (s2[i]>='a' && s2[i] <= 'z')
          {
              lower[j++] = s2[i];
          }
          else
          {
               //print something or just exit...
          }
      }
  }
  //add the string terminator character
  lower[j] = '\0';
  upper[k] = '\0';

  //print the result
  printf ("Upper: %s\n", upper);
  printf ("Lower: %s\n", lower);
  ```

This should do the job.

Comment: yes :) this worked and i understand it thanks very much all of you for the assistance i'll keep all your pointers in mind...thanks again

Comment: @Pandrei Minor: `for (i=0; i<strlen(s1); ...` unnecessarily recalculates the length of a string, which takes `n` time - and this is done`n` times so `O(n*n)`.  Better to `len = strlen(s1); for (i=0; i<len; ...`  Obviously not a big issue with a string of size 25.

Comment: @chux actually that is not true, the compiler will precompute the value of strlen(s1)/strlen(s2) even before if gets to the for loops as part of the optimization process. So it's actually the same as doing it explicitly in the code.

Comment: @Pandrei A compiler may do that optimization only if if "knows" is the `strlen()` we all know and love and not some other `strlen()` that has side effects.  Further, that single call, as you comment, can only be employed if the compiler analyzes all possible execution paths in the loop to insure `s1` did not change.  This is a tall order that many compilers simply can not meet.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049480/how-many-times-will-strlen-be-called-in-this-for-loop

Answer (score 1):

In your code, in the usage of [`strcat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat)

```
 strcat (s1, s2);
```

`s1` is probably not having enough memory to hold the concatenated string. In that case, it invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

From the man page,

> If `dest` is not large enough, program behavior is unpredictable; buffer overruns are a favorite avenue for attacking secure programs.

As per your requirement

> `The maximum size of each string is 25`

You need a destination buffer of length 25 X 2 (for `char`s) + 1 (for null).

Also, it indicates, you need `s1` and `s2` to have `26` elements, each, for accommodating the null.

As per your requirement, there are certain design changes required to your program, as

1. you need `s1` and `s2` to have `26` elements, each, for accommodating the null.
2. `upper` and `lower` both must have a size of total of the input size. Think of the scenario if `s1` and `s2` are both completely UPPERCASE (or lowercase). So, you need `upper[51]` and `lower[51]`.

Comment: @RhysHinkson regarding buffer size? I'll add a line.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i have so far: :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N   25

int main(void)
{
    char s1[N];
    char s2[N];
    char *upper, *lower;
    char *p, *q;
    size_t n1, n2;

    printf( "Please enter first string: " );
    fgets( s1, N, stdin );

    printf( "Please enter second string: " );
    fgets( s2, N, stdin );

    n1 = 0; n2 = 0;

    for ( p = s1; *p; ++p )
    {
        if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++n1;
        else if ( islower( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++n2;
    }

    for ( p = s2; *p; ++p )
    {
        if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++n1;
        else if ( islower( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++n2;
    }

    upper = NULL; lower = NULL;

    if ( n1 && ( upper = ( char * )malloc( n1 + 1 ) ) )
    {
        q = upper;

        for ( p = s1; *p; ++p )
        {
            if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) *q++ = *p;
        }

        for ( p = s2; *p; ++p )
        {
            if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) *q++ = *p;
        }

        *q = '\0';
    }       

    if ( n2 && ( lower = ( char * )malloc( n1 + 1 ) ) )
    {
        q = lower;

        for ( p = s1; *p; ++p )
        {
            if ( islower( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) *q++ = *p;
        }

        for ( p = s2; *p; ++p )
        {
            if ( islower( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) *q++ = *p;
        }

        *q = '\0';
    }       

    if ( upper ) printf( "Upper: %s\n", upper );
    if ( lower ) printf( "Lower: %s\n", lower );

    free( upper );
    free( lower );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Please enter first string: GREENblue
Please enter second string: busCAR
Upper: GREENCAR
Lower: bluebus
```

If your compiler supports Variable Length Arrays then you could use VLA(s) instead of the dynamically allocated arrays.

Here is a program that uses VLA

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N   25

int main(void)
{
    char s1[N];
    char s2[N];

    printf( "Please enter first string: " );
    fgets( s1, N, stdin );

    printf( "Please enter second string: " );
    fgets( s2, N, stdin );

    size_t n1 = 0, n2 = 0;

    for ( const char *p = s1; *p; ++p )
    {
        if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++n1;
        else if ( islower( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++n2;
    }

    for ( const char *p = s2; *p; ++p )
    {
        if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++n1;
        else if ( islower( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++n2;
    }


    char upper[n1 + 1];
    char lower[n2 + 1];

    if ( n1 )
    {
        char *q = upper;

        for ( const char *p = s1; *p; ++p )
        {
            if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) *q++ = *p;
        }

        for ( const char *p = s2; *p; ++p )
        {
            if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) *q++ = *p;
        }

        *q = '\0';
    }       

    if ( n2 )
    {
        char *q = lower;

        for ( const char *p = s1; *p; ++p )
        {
            if ( islower( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) *q++ = *p;
        }

        for ( const char *p = s2; *p; ++p )
        {
            if ( islower( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) *q++ = *p;
        }

        *q = '\0';
    }       

    if ( n1 ) printf( "Upper: %s\n", upper );
    if ( n2 ) printf( "Lower: %s\n", lower );


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You still have a problem: what happens if you enter a string that is longer than 23 characters? Your program will crash.

If the maximum size is to be 25 characters, your arrays have to be dimensioned 26, not 25, to account for the terminating NULL.

Then you have to set the s1[N-1]='\0' and s2[N-1] = '\n'  for safety.
If you enter something too long for the first string, the second string will end up being the residual characters, ignoring anything you entered after the prompt for the second string.

Comment: Detail: `scanf("%s", &s1);` (which should be `scanf("%s", s1);` or better `scanf("%24s", s1);`) will not save a `'\n'` in `s1`.  Code has trouble if user input exceeds 24 non-white-space characters, not 23.