# Print String Without Padded 0 At The End

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, c-strings

I am trying to print the string `"Hello"` in binary.

I get it to work, however, I would like it to print without the padded at the end

so

```
  01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111
```

instead of

```
  01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00000000
```

Here is my code:

```
char t[] = "Hello";

for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(t); j++)
{
    unsigned char c = t[j];

    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d", (c >> i) & 1 ? 1 : 0);
    }

    printf(" ");

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can modify your loop condition as:

```
for (int j = 0; t[j] != '\0'; j++)
/*              ^^^^^^^^^^^^     */
```

Currently you loop for all characters in `t[]` that even include the trailing `nul` character. With modified condition you exit the loop on seeing the `nul` character responsible for trailing zeros.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| H | e | l | l | o |\0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  T   T   T   T   T   F   t[i] != '\0'

sizeof(t) = 6
strlen(t) = 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Or just:

```
 for (int j = 0; j < (sizeof(t)-1); j++)
```

to avoid printing the trailing character `nul`.

Answer (score 2):

Logically, you should just do:

```
for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(t) - 1; j++)
```

When you do sizeof(t) the null character at the end of the string is also counted and therefore printed.

Another fix would be:

```
for (int j = 0; t[j] != '\0'; j++)
```

Comment: in the second option, strlen() is executed again and again in the loop. You should avoid such a behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This `j < sizeof(t);` rotates loop number of character plus one more(nul character) times). Instead of this rotate loop until `\0` character not occur. For e.g

```
for (int j = 0; t[j]; j++) { }
```

Sample working code

```
char t[] = "Hello";
for (int j = 0; t[j] != '\0'; j++) /* using t[j]!='\0'  is much quicker than using strlen(t) */
{
    unsigned char c = t[j];
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d", (c >> i) & 1); /* No need to use ternary operator */
    }
    printf(" ");
}
```

Find a good read regarding not to use `strlen()` in `for` loop condition : [Is using strlen() in the loop condition slower than just checking for the null character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388029/is-using-strlen-in-the-loop-condition-slower-than-just-checking-for-the-null-c)

Comment: Isn't `strlen(t)` evaluated in each iteration?

Comment: @Achal But wouldn't the compiler be smart enough to optimize that anyway?

Comment: @Achal Cool, this is better.